# Calculating PI with an special Algorithm

Tags: java

I have to calculate PI with this special algorithm for school:

```
pi = 4*(1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 ... 1/n)
```

I've been trying a lot of things but it seems like I only get a never-ending loop because the condition for it is false, or my code is too complicated. The result I have to get is the **calculated PI (only 6 decimals)=(the Algorithm for it)**.

Here's the code I've already tried:

```java
public void PI()
{
    double n=1.0;//while 3 counter
    double z=1.0;//while 3 denominator
    int i=0;//numerator for while 3
    double pi=1.0;//Result
    double x=0.0;//Calculated fractions
    double y=1.0;//denominator for double x
    double q=1; //Help for while 2
    int f=0;//Help for while 3
    while(new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*pi)).compareTo(new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*Math.PI)))==-1||new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*pi)).compareTo(new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*Math.PI)))==1) //while 1
    {
        while(new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*(4*x))).compareTo(new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*Math.PI)))==-1||new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*pi)).compareTo(new Double(Math.round(1000000.0*Math.PI)))==1)//while 2
        {
            if (q==1)
            {
                x+=0.1/y;
                q++;
            }
            y+=2;
            if(q==2)
            {
              x-=0.1/y; 
              q--;
            }
            y+=2;
            i++;
        }
        pi=x*4.0;
    }

    while(f<=i)//while 3
    {
        System.out.println(n+"/"+z);
        z+=2;
        f++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging the code? The easiest would be to calculate `Math.round(1000000.0*pi)` etc. as variables inside the loop. You could then easily see which values you get and this will give a clue what's going wrong. As your question stands now, you're simply asking us to debug your code for you.

Comment: It would also make sense to include your "algorithm" as text, not as a link to JPG. I mean, how much effort is it to retype what's on the image?

Comment: I have debugged it a lot of times but I can’t get further because it gets stuck in while 2 and it takes a lot of effort to calculate a fractions with millions of decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks overcomplicated. Try this:

```
/**
 * Returns PI estimation based on equation:
 * {@code PI' = 4*(1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 ... 1/m)}
 * 
 * @param n number of fractions in sum.
 */ 
public static double piEstimate(int n) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double fraction = (double) 1/(i*2+1);
        int sign = (i % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
        sum += sign * fraction;
    }
    return 4*sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("PI = " + piEstimate(10000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a System.out.println to see how the pi variable evolves in your second loop.

Comment: I did that but I only get a really long number and after a minute the Programm gets stuck

Comment: As your loop won't stop until the pi variable is bigger than PI that means your algorithm is not working properly.